Trying to modify background color
When I'm trying to modify my bg color, only my title background color change, can someone help me ?
I think it's due to the fact that there's an other bg color specified in my css, but I can't get to write something over it. The reason why there's a weir variable in my js is because I'm going to use when I fix my current issue.


function random(nombre){
    l = Math.random *255
    return Math.floor(l)
}

let btn = document.querySelector("button")
btn.onclick = function () {
    var rndCol =
      "rgb(" + random(255) + "," + random(255) + "," + random(255) + ")";
    document.body.style.cssText += "background: red;" ;
}
h1{
    color : red;
}
header{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
html{
    background: yellow;
}
main{
    position: relative;
    top : 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#jesuispuissant{
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top : 22px;
    right : -5px;
    background: green;
}
<header id = "test">
    <h1> Ce site peut changer de couleur</h1>
</header>
<main>
    <h2> Il se passe quelque chose si vous appuyez sur  ce bouton</h2>
    <button id = 'jesuispuissant'> Appuyer dessus</button>
</main>




It's because you have a background set for html as well - see mentioned duplicate, as for what effects that can have. And rather than adding to cssText, you should probably set only the background-color specifically: document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";

The onclick function doesn't do anything with the random color it builds either. It generates the rndCol variable and sets the background color to red.
